# javascript, returning true when it's false whenever I would try to calculate the average of parameters

Tags: javascript

```
function passingAverage(n){
    var average = 0, i;
    for (i=0; i < n.length; i+= 1){
        average += n[i];
    }
    if ((average/n.length)<49)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

in this code, I compare the numbers given in the console.log and just calculate for average.

```
console.log('passingAverage(75,42,98) returns: ' + passingAverage(75,42,98));
console.log('passingAverage(34,93,77,89,49) returns: ' + passingAverage(34,93,77,89,49));
console.log('passingAverage(33,61) returns: ' + passingAverage(33,61));

console.log("\n");
```

for console.log(passing average(75,42,98) and (34,93,77,89,49) indeed does return true which is correct. But, for the console log(33,61), when the 33+61/2 isn't clearly above 49, it returns true automatically for some reason when it should return false. What could be the reason?

Comment: You're passing multiple arguments to your function but only using the first

Comment: Your function expects an array, but you're passing in some individual numbers. In the case of passingAverage(75,42,98), `n` will be equal to 75, `n.length` will be equal to `undefined`, average will stay at 0, and your condition `(0 / undefined) < 49` evaluates to `NaN < 49`, which always evaluates to false. Thus, true is always returned

Comment: There is a mistake. You pass some numbers but you try to treat it like an array. Pass an array or just write _function passingAverage(...n)_

Comment: This question is really an example of how one should debug a problem. If you looked at the `n` that you received in your function you'd see the issue right away

Comment: so How would I can make my function takes unknown number that matches the number of parameters for console.log statements?

Comment: never mind, fixed it! Thank you guys

Comment: `return [].reduce.call(arguments, (a, b) => a + b) / arguments.length >= 49;` – in a nutshell…

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're not passing an array as expected. `passingAverage(33,61)` pass two parameters.

If you want the function to have the same signature as you define it in the example you provided, then you should call it like this:

```
passingAverage([33,61]); // pass an array of elements
```

If you want to call the funtion like `passingAverage(33,61)` then the function should be defined like this:

```
function passingAverage(){ // no arguments, we will use the arguments array
    var n = arguments; // arguments is defined for every function it's an array of all the arguments passed in

    var average = 0, i;
    for (i=0; i < n.length; i+= 1){
        average += n[i];
    }
    if ((average/n.length)<49)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

// then call the function like this
passingAverage(1, 65, 23, 22); // without using an array
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect example of why it's best to use [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) rather than console.logs to debug your code. Your function is always returning `true` because your average is always [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN):

```js
function passingAverage(n) {
  var average = 0, i;
  for (i = 0; i < n.length; i += 1) {
    average += n[i];
  }
  return average / n.length
}

console.log('passingAverage(75,42,98) returns: ' + passingAverage(75,42,98));
console.log('passingAverage(34,93,77,89,49) returns: ' + passingAverage(34,93,77,89,49));
console.log('passingAverage(33,61) returns: ' + passingAverage(33,61));
```

This is because you're passing two distinct float arguments to your method, which is in fact expecting an array of values:

```js
function passingAverage(n) {
  console.log("arguments:", n);
  var average = 0, i;
  for (i = 0; i < n.length; i += 1) {
    average += n[i];
  }
  return average / n.length
}
passingAverage(75,42,98);
```

Simply pass your values as an array and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

use `arguments` to loop over **ALL** function arguments regardless of length.

```
function passingAverage() {
    var average = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        average += arguments[i];
    }
    if ((average/n.length)<49)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```